# Specify timeout for New-AzureStorageAccount cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

Is there a way I could specify a timeout value while using the [New-AzureStorageAccount] cmdlet?

While creating a storage account via powershell, I get this error sporadically...

> New-AzureStorageAccount : The HTTP request to
>   'https://management.core.windows.net/XXXX/operations/YYYY' has
>   exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9930000. The time allotted
>   to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. At
>   C:\Temp\20130305_150221\somefile.ps1:212 char:36
>   +             New-AzureStorageAccount <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageAccount], TimeoutException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.NewAzureStorageAccountCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  There currently isn't a way to set a timeout for this command, filed an sisue in the github repository for powershell:: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/1175

If you're interested in a quick fix, since this is an open source project, you should be able to set the timeout through code and compile your own fix in VS.